# Создание раздела "Аудирование" для электронного учебника

Tags: php, аудио, mysql

Суть такая, будет раздел электронного учебника (на php+mysql). В нем раздел "Аудирование".
Т.е. там будет какой-то мр3-файл с голосом диктора, его нужно прослушать и выполнить задания.
Я представил это так.
Так должен выглядеть список страниц:
[image]

Так выглядит прослушивание: 
[image]

После раздумий у меня такое вырисовалось.

БД:

```
create table audio
(
id int primary key auto_increment,
title varchar(255) not null,
link varchar(255) not null
)
```

Где `LINK` - ссылка на файл после загрузки (т.е. загрузили файл 1.mp3 он отправился в `http://site.kz/uploads/1.mp3`, так вот всё, что жирным шрифтом, будет в `Link`). Не знаю, правильно ли выбрал тип.

На главной выведется через `$result=select * from audio where id=$переменная, по которой пришли`

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
( $row['id']  $row['title'], $row['link'])
```

Далее плеер (понравился  http://www.ph4.ru/form_audionsite.ph4)

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="player/player.swf" id=audioplayer1 height=24 width=290>
<param name=movie value="player/player.swf"></param>
<param name=FlashVars 
value="playerID=1&soundFile='$row['link']' ">
</param>
<param name=quality value=high></param>
<param name=menu value=false></param>
<param name=wmode value=transparent></param>
</object>
```

Теперь вопрос.
Как мне затащить путь полный до файла в переменную?
Я жму обзор, выбираю файл, потом пишу `TITLE` и жму добавить. Путь как-то должен записаться в БД в link.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно уловил вопрос, то как-то так:
1) Делаешь примерно такую форму для загрузки файла на сервер:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="file_title">
  <input type="file" name="file_name">
  <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

2)На странице-обработчике(к примеру add.php) что-то такое:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST["file"]) or empty($_POST["title"])){
  exit("Вы не ввели всех данных");
}
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'])){
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], "/uploads/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
}
else { exit("Во время загрузки произошла ошибка"); }
$file=("/uploads/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
$title=$_POST['title'];
?>

<textarea>
<h3><?php print $title; ?></h3><br>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
data="player/player.swf" id=audioplayer1 height=24 width=290>
<param name=movie value="player/player.swf"></param>
<param name=FlashVars 
value="playerID=1&soundFile=<?php print $file; ?>">
</param>
<param name=quality value=high></param>
<param name=menu value=false></param>
<param name=wmode value=transparent></param>
</object>
</textarea>
```

Ну вот если меня нигде не занесло то в итоге тебе выдаст бокс в котором будет код на нужный плеер.
Там с этим плеером еще есть фишка - **id=audioplayer1** с каждым новым плеером id нужно прибавлять еденицу(id=audioplayer2, id=audioplayer3...).

Маленькое приложение:
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'] - имя файла до его отправки на сервер, например, pict.gif;
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'] - размер принятого файла в байтах;
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'] - MIME-тип принятого файла (если браузер смог его определить), например: image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, text/html;
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'] - содержит имя файла во временном каталоге, например: /tmp/phpV3b3qY;
    $_FILES['uploadfile']['error'] - Код ошибки, которая может возникнуть при загрузке файла.